# GNOME 3.34 vs Deepin Desktop Environment - resources usage

Tags: gnome, desktop-environment, deepin

GNOME 3.34 has been released few days ago, and changes list sounds promising, but what about resources usage and overall performance especially compared with Deepin Desktop Environment, which is my DE of choice? Btw, I'm Arch Linux user :)